# How to create compound adjectives for these sentences?

Tags: grammar

A girl that has dark hair is "a dark-haired girl"
A man that looks good is "a good-looking man"

What about the following?

A sky that is illuminated by the moon is a ...?
An experience that opens your eyes is a...?
A stove/oven that cleans itself is a ...?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint- you take the noun that is the object (or a slightly modified version of it) and the present progressive tense of the verb.

Comment: I should say sometimes the verb is in the past participle form, e.g. “moonlit” (“moon-illuminated” is not a normal expression. And “moonlighting” means something else entirely).

Comment: Rather than just posting a sequence of unrelated questions, you could improve your post by editing in your best attempt to answer them, along with why you doubt your attempt is correct.  This looks like a homework exercise, and you will learn better if you first attempt it yourself and try to explain why you are unsure.

Answer (score 1):

This does sound like a homework question. Instead of answering directly, I can help you understand the structure of compounds.

Let's look at your first question, "a sky that is illuminated by the moon". With a structure like

> A SOMETHING that is VERB by/with SOMETHINGELSE

you can derive a compound of the form

> SOMETHINGELSE-VERB SOMETHING.

For instance, "a forest filled with light" is a **light-filled forest**.

(Note that in your particular example, it's best that you use the verb light instead of illuminated, as in "a sky that is lit by the moon").

The second question, "an experience that opens your eyes", is actually similar to the structure described above, except that it uses the active voice instead of passive.

> A SOMETHING that VERBs SOMETHINGELSE

From here you can derive a compound of the form

> A SOMETHINGELSE-VERBing SOMETHING.

For instance, "an idea that blows your mind" is a **mind-blowing idea**.

The third question uses the same structure as the second one, so you should be good to go here.

Good luck.